# Advantage of embedded scripts in html to save an extra HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking at why embedding scripts in HTML are better than using external scripts and one point was that it saves an extra HTTP request. But I want to know how would this link to a real life situation? Can someone give me an example of this happening and how?

Thank you.

Comment: not really unless you're running really big company and it saves you a ton of dollars to reduce even a byte of response. or if you're actually targeting audience with very low speeds

Comment: @MehulMohan that's not actually true.  The difference in bytes is not the issue, it's the # of requests, which affect the user's experience.

Answer (score 0):

When a browser gets an HTML file, it parses that file to figure out what to display. Anytime it hits a tag that requires an additional resource (eg script tag with a src attribute, img tag link etc) it will send another request to download that resource.

I think embedding the JavaScript code in the page isn't the best solution, as it means you can't let the browser cache the JS that's common across all pages, but it is good to concatenate and minify scripts so that you only download one or two bundles.

There's a lot of good discussion at the YSlow site:  http://yslow.org/

Comment: Thank you, I'm just confused if you embed the script it means the browser has to download less resource, therefore, loads faster? I thought using external scripts were faster as they are cached.

Comment: It's a little more complex than that.  Every script you don't embed is another request to a server.  That can be cached, and so it's only an impact on the initial page load or for clients that don't cache (rare, but it happens).  The other limit to page load speed there is that most browsers limit the number of concurrent requests to the same domain, so if you have a lot of scripts for example, then you get benefit from using a CDN.